# How to use nvidia component to accelerate usb camera (v4l2src or nvv4l2camerasrc) on Jetson Nano with Python3 OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer, nvidia-jetson-nano

My goal is to accelerate the **USB-CAMERA** on **JetsonNano** with **`Python` `cv2`** package. Trying to use some gstreaner plugin like `nvv4l2decoder` or `nvjpegdec` or `(memory:NVMM)`.

Python Code:

```py
import cv2

width = 1920
height = 1080

gs_pipeline = f"v4l2src device=/dev/video0 io-mode=2 " \
              f"! image/jpeg, width={width}, height={height}" \
              f"! nvv4l2decoder mjpeg=1 " \
              f"! nvvidconv " \
              f"! video/x-raw(memory:NVMM) format=BGR" \
              f"! videoconvert " \
              f"! video/x-raw, format=BGR " \
              f"! appsink"

v_cap = cv2.VideoCapture(gs_pipeline, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)
if not v_cap.isOpened():
    print("failed to open video capture")
    exit(-1)

while v_cap.isOpened():
    ret_val, frame = v_cap.read()
    if not ret_val:
        break

    cv2.imshow('', frame)

    input_key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if input_key != -1:
        print(f"input key = {input_key}")

    if input_key == ord('q'):
        break
```

Error:

```
[ WARN:0] global /home/nvidia/host/build_opencv/nv_opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (711) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Error opening bin: could not parse caps "video/x-raw(memory:NVMM) format=BGR"
[ WARN:0] global /home/nvidia/host/build_opencv/nv_opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (480) isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
```

Another point to mention, some of the `gst-launch-1.0` command can work, but it does not mean it can work in python as well. The ultimate goal is to use `python` `cv2` to control the camera.

Only Command Line Worked Example:

```bash
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 io-mode=2 ! image/jpeg, width=1920, height=1080, framerate=30/1, format=MJPG ! nvjpegdec ! 'video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=I420,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1' ! nvegltransform ! nveglglessink
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nvvidconv doesn't support BGR, only BGRx (thus the videoconvert for BGRx->BGR). Caps also lacks a comma.
Last, videoconvert only supports system memory, so have nvvidconv to output into system memory rather than NVMM memory.
So change:

```
gs_pipeline = f"v4l2src device=/dev/video0 io-mode=2 " \
              f"! image/jpeg, width={width}, height={height}, framerate=30/1, format=MJPG " \
              f"! nvv4l2decoder mjpeg=1 " \
              f"! nvvidconv " \
              f"! video/x-raw, format=BGRx " \
              f"! videoconvert " \
              f"! video/x-raw, format=BGR " \
              f"! appsink drop=1"
```

Comment: Sorry I missed that. Edited my answer for fixing that.

Comment: I got some warning:
```Opening in BLOCKING MODE
Opening in BLOCKING MODE 
NvMMLiteOpen : Block : BlockType = 277 
NVMEDIA: Reading vendor.tegra.display-size : status: 6 
NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 277```

And the biggest problem is: the program stuck at the line ```v_cap.read()``` and not showing any frames.

Comment: I've added framerate and MJPG format into caps after v4l2src. Does that help ? The message is not a warning, it is just a normal trace.

Comment: Sometimes the frame is not showing, I guess it's probably the previous run not closing gracefully, are there any commands to release the NVMM?

Comment: You would just try adding `v_cap.release()` when you get out of the loop. You may also add drop=1 to appsink properties : `... ! appsink drop=1`.

Comment: I've done handle of ```v_cap.release()```, but I found that sometimes the program keep pending on the line of creating cv2.VideoCapture, any other idea?

Comment: Not so much advice, sorry...Try adding a queue before appsink. This may be related to your camera driver or USB issues...try checking with `sudo dmesg --follow` if there are some kernel messages when the issue happens.